# Python Keras Image Recognition obtain accurate probabiliy(Not [[0.]] or [[1.]])

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I am learning to code CNN with keras. The tutorial I am following is based on [this tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html), and everything works pretty well.

But, I played a bit with this CNN, tried to optimize it, and try to find it's limit. It appears that when I present a picture of something that is not a cat or a dog, let's say a chair, the CNN still tells me the picture is a dog.

Since the model is trained only on dogs and cats images, it can only tell me if if the image is a dog or cat. Thus I decided to use `model.predict_proba` in order to get an accurate probability, so I wanted the model to tell me, in the case of a picture of chair, "There is 7% probabilty this is a dog". But the model gives me `[[0.]]`, in other words, the model is 100% sure a chair is a dog.

Then, I started modifying the CNN, and I put 2 output neurones in the fully connected layers, in order to have the probabilty that it's a cat, and the probabilty that it's a dog. I used `class_mode='categorical'` instead of `class_mode='binary'` in the data preparation, to be sure it works with the 2 output neurones, and I didn't use `softmax`, to be sure that I don't have `probaDog + probaCat = 1`, because, if the input is a picture of something else than a dog or a cat, I don't want to obtain false probabilities...
What I wanted to see, when I typed `model.predict_proba("iamge_path")`, was something like that `[[0.213 0.639]]`. 
Then I wanted to be able to define some conditions and use them like that:

```
if result[0][0] < 0.5 AND result[0][1] < 0.5:
    print("This is neither a dog nor a cat!")
elif result[0][0] > result[0][1] + 0.5:
    print("This is a dog!")
elif result[0][1] > result[0][0] + 0.5:
    print("This is a cat!")
else:
    print("This is neither a dog nor a cat!")
```

But instead, every single answer I get is `[[0. 1.]]` or `[[1. 0.]]`.

I tried training my CNN on only 1 epoch. I presented 13 pictures of cat to that CNN, and it told me 7 times it was dogs. But it was 100% percent sure it was dogs...

So, how do we get true probabilty?

**Here is my CNN code:**

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, input_shape=(128, 128, 3), activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Convolution2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, strides=1, activation = "relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=128, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.2))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation="sigmoid")) # 2 neurones de sorties

model.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "binary_crossentropy", metrics = ["accuracy"])
```

**Here is my data preparation code:**

```
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/training_set',
        target_size=(128, 128),   
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'dataset/test_set',
        target_size=(128, 128),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical')
```

**The training code:**

```
model.fit_generator(
                        training_set,
                        steps_per_epoch=250, 
                        epochs=50,
                        validation_data=test_set,
                        validation_steps=63)
```

**The code to test on a single image:**

```
test_image = image.load_img(image_path, target_size=(128, 128)) 
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image) 
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0) 
result = model.predict(test_image)
print(model.predict_proba(test_image))
```

Comment: This is not a programming problem, but a open research problem. Its not a matter of just adding some code or function, but in general there is no established way to detect out of sample inputs.

Comment: Wow really? So, if I want to use a CNN that looks into a folder that contains hundreds of images of any kind and returns me only the images that represent a cat, what would be the strategy?
The only strategy I can think of is to have a 3rd training folder, apart from "cats" and "dogs", that would be "other". Put other pictures in that folder and train the CNN with these 3 folders. But the the problem is that "other" is very vast. It would take a lot of pictures of other animals, objects, landscapes, abstract pictures... that would be massive.
Is there a better strategy for that problem?

Comment: I think your code is correct.  It should return probability, not exactly 0 or 1.  A possible reason why you get 100% confidence from the model is that it is overfitted.

Comment: It's not even overfitted. To make sure overfitting wasn't the problem I tried training the CNN on only 1 epoch. And it still gives me probability of 100%, even when it's wrong. I guess it's like Matias Valdenegro said. It's still an open research problem...